# Using an IFRAME for a simple advertisment. Is it bad for SEO?

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe, seo, ads

If you look [here](http://ads.lockedonmedia.com/zones/204) you will see an ad that is intended to be embedded in another site as an advertisement. [Here](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/world/2010/03/02/2010-03-02_chilean_earthquake_may_have_shortened_earth_day_by_microsecond_nasa.html) is an example of where it is embedded.

The code responsible for displaying the ad in the web site is this:

```
<iframe src="http://ads.lockedonmedia.com/zones/204" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 160px; height: 600px;">
```

I like this approach in that, if the advertisement include dynamic content, such as "today's price," the content will be easily reflected in the hosting web page.

My question is this:

I realize that IFRAMEs present navigational issues, but is there a real impact on SEO and should SEO-sensitive developers avoid using it at all costs or are there circumstances where it can be used w/o harming your ranking?

Comment: see http://www.straightupsearch.com/archives/2008/05/seo_iframes_a_g.html

Comment: Interesting. I think it confirmed my gut, that using IFRAME is fine for advertisement since one wouldn't expect the content of the advertisement to be considered my web site's content. Unless there are other reasons, so far it seems like a green-light for using IFRAMES for small ads. It seems like "lockedonmedia", (see code  above) uses this approach extensively.

Comment: Ironically a story was released on cnet where the attack I mentioned happened to TechCrunch and Drudge Report http://news.cnet.com/8301-27080_3-20000353-245.html?tag=mncol;title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind with using an Iframe for advertisements, never ever ever embed a raw location into it! If you use an Iframe pointing to a URL as your ad source at some point your website will become an attack site for serving malware from a nefarious advertiser that changes their legitimate advertisement to a malicious one.

Comment: By "raw" do you mean "hard coded referenced domain?" It sound like your concern, which sounds valid, is that the host simply needs a dynamic way to "turn off" these ads without changing the code, should they become malicious. Did I get the point?

Comment: By raw I mean any direct url that you do not own. As in ads.lockedonmedia.com/zones/204 should be a url you own otherwise you should serve the content through some kind of proxy that will scrub all javascript (most specifically) and perhaps flash (if your comfortable with not allowing flash ads).